# Google chart grid lines color syntax

Tags: bar-chart, gridlines, column-chart

According to official Google documentation, to change the color of grid you need to right something like

```
{vAxis: {gridlines: {color: '#f0f'}}}
```

Even if I use same library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

The code above does not work. Instead I found and I use

```
{vAxis: {gridlineColor: '#f0f'}}
```

Can anyone explain why the official documentation is wrong ?

Comment: I just tested it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/72fyxbk9/. I added 'color: "red"' on line 22, it does work.

Comment: I tried vAxis: { gridlineColor: '#f0f'} and it also worke. So in your code from jsfidle both methods are ok. But in my code just Second method it work. Why ? Is so frustraiting.

Comment: you better post your code. what I posted is google's official code.